# TV Saint Seiya Prologue theme

Tags: saint-seiya

In Sanctuary chapter, after opening, there is a prologue for the events of the last episode. I can't find the name of that music theme, and "Galaxian Wars" is not that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the one you are looking for: [Intense! Cosmo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0V7MLiIEqc4&ab_channel=Awesmic)

Answer (score -1):

It should be "Galaxian Wars" composed by Seiji Yokoyama. You can easily find it on Youtube. Try make sure of it.

Comment: Is another one that I'm looking for. Galaxian Wars is played mostly but, I'm searching for the one is played at the first episodes (Phoenix Saga, Silver Saints)

Comment: Ah, sorry it is "Intence! Cosmos". Try youtube. My friend uploaded the video.